# WordPress Share Menus Between Themes?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am creating a base wordpress theme to use as a starting point for all my sites to come.

in my base theme i have a couple custom menus for the heaer and footer.

**how can i declare those menus in a way that all my other themes (using the same base) will inherit them?**

Answer (score 0):

Use child themes. http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
Your header.php and other common template parts will be kept in the parent themes and the other files (like page.php, single.php, etc.) will be overriden in the child themes.

Comment: i just tried that. when i switched form the main theme to the child theme i still needed to go to menus to set them. i want "xyz menu" value to be global.

Comment: Please be more precise. Explain where will your themes be in the end. On different domains? It is not clear to me what "all your sites to come" are. Are you talking about multiple blogs in a single WordPress installation or multiple WordPress installations? Also, are you talking about the possibility to keep the menu structure somewhere and when changing it, having the modifications reflect in all child themes? Explain more.